# Php contact form open a new page

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm building a website and have I a `php` contact form.

Validation of the form and `mail()` function is working perfectly.

My `php` file for the form is `handler.php`.

Now to the problem. When I press the submit button and a error message is coming up, they comes up in a new blank page and that page is the same `URL` but it added `/handler.php` in the `URL`.

What i want to do is make the error messages show up under the form, and if it is no errors I want it to go to my `thankyoumessage.html`.

This is the `php` code for the form:

```
<?php

/*Set the mail of the reciever*/
$myemail  = "mymail@example.com";

/*Display error message*/
function show_error($myError)
    {
    ?>
        <html>
        <body>

        <b>Var snäll och rätta till följande fel:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>

        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
    exit();
    }
    
/* Check inputs */
function check_input($data, $problem='error')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    // if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    // {
    //     show_error($problem);
    // }
    return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message'])) 
{

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $name = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['name']));
    $subject  = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['subject']));
    $email    = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['email']));
    $message = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['message']));

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("Email adressen är inte giltig...");
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
    /*If name is empty show error message */
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) 
    {
        show_error("Du måste skriva in ditt namn...");
    }
    /*If email is empty show error message */
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) 
    {
        show_error("Du måste skriva in din email...");
    }
    /*If message is empty show error message */
    if (empty($_POST['message'])) 
    {
        show_error("Ett meddelande krävs om du önskar att få hjälp av oss...");
    }

    /* Prepare the message for the e-mail */
    $mail =utf8_decode("
    Hej!

    Ditt kontakt formulär har blivit besvarat av:

    Namn: $name

    E-mail: $email

    Kundens meddelande:
    $message

    Meddelande slut.
    ");
    
    echo "Tack för du kontaktar oss! \n Vi återkommer med ett svar så snart som möjligt!";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $mail);
}
else
{
    ?><span><?php echo "Fyll i alla fälten...";?></span> <?php
}
?>
```

And this is the `Html` to the form:

```
<form class="mt-5 ml-5 mr-5" method="POST" action="handler.php" id="reused_form">
        <p id="contactForm" class="h4 text-center mt-5"><strong>Kontakta oss</strong></p>

        <!-- input text(Name) -->
        <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix">*</i>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
            <label>Ditt namn</label>
        </div>

        <!-- input email -->
        <div class="md-form mt-5">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix">*</i>
            <input type="email" id="name" name="email" id="email" class="form-control validate">
            <label data-error="Fel" data-success="Rätt">Din email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="md-form mt-5">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
            <label>Ämne</label>
        </div>

        <!-- input message -->
        <div class="md-form mt-5">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil prefix">*</i>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" maxlength="5000" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            <label>Meddelande</label>
        </div>

        <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
            <button class="btn danger-color" name="submit" type="submit">Skicka</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: add this to your php script just after declaring `<?php` - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` and you should see the cause of your issue

Comment: Well your current setup is a simple form action is taking the user to `handler.php` regardless. What you're describing requires AJAX. So you need a layer of JavaScript to intercept the form submission, send the data instead over AJAX, then do one of two things (show error message or go to thank you page) when result is received.

Comment: Submit the same form via ajax if error show the error, otherwise you can redirect to the thanksyou page

Comment: So I cant do it without `AJAX` ? @Utkanos

Comment: I agree with @Utkanos. If you do not want to leave the page if some error occurr, you will need to use ajax to process the server response and check for errors to, then, show any error message.

Comment: @luddep - to do what you're describing, no. Great time to learn AJAX, i.e. page transition-less data transactions.

Comment: @Utkanos - I have looked in to AJAX but I cannot seem to understand how i should do with it to make it work..

Comment: @luddep - AJAX is pretty much essential for modern web dev. The concept is you transmit/fetch data to/from the server without the need for a page load. The good thing is your server-side scripts (PHP) need not change much at all to accommodate AJAX, if at all. The difference is almost totally on the client. It's well worth delving into AJAX. Then you can post some AJAX-specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: @Utkanos Ok, well thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Utkanos - I think I'm getting crazy on this... totally lost when it comes to this, And if I post a new question its just going to be down voted beacuse I dont know what to ask for, right now nothing is working beacuse I have removed `action="handler.php"`

Comment: First of all, learn how to submit a form over AJAX. This is usually done by attaching a `submit` event to the form, then canceling default event action (the page transition-style submission) via `evt.preventDefault()`. You would then gather up the form data yourself, e.g. via [jQuery's `serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). You then listen for a response via a callback passed to `.done(function(response) { alert('PHP script said '+response); })`.

Comment: Basic fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mitya33/b5o974vf/7/ - also, there are countless questions and tutorials on there on converting conventional forms to AJAX use.

Comment: Thank you very mutch! - @Utkanos

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use AJAX, You can just let the mail() function process the form in the same page as the following :

```
<?php 
// we declare empty error variables
$error = $error_email = $error_name = $error_subject = $error_message = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $name = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['name']));
    $subject  = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['subject']));
    $email    = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['email']));
    $message = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['message']));

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        $error_email = "Email adressen är inte giltig...";

    }
    /*If name is empty show error message */
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) 
    {
         $error_name = "Du måste skriva in ditt namn...";
    }
    /*If email is empty show error message */
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) 
    {
         $error_email = "Du måste skriva in din email...";
    }
    /*If message is empty show error message */
    if (empty($_POST['message'])) 
    {
         $error_message = "Ett meddelande krävs om du önskar att få hjälp av oss...";
    }

    /// You can add the subject validations here as well
    if (empty($_POST['subject'])) 
    {
         $error_subject = "Ett meddelande krävs om du önskar att få hjälp av oss...";
    }

    /* Prepare the message for the e-mail */
    $mail =utf8_decode("
    Hej!

    Ditt kontakt formulär har blivit besvarat av:

    Namn: $name

    E-mail: $email

    Kundens meddelande:
    $message

    Meddelande slut.
    ");

    if(mail($myemail, $subject, $mail))
    {
    /// We redirect to the thank you mesage uppon a successful message sending
     header("Location:thankyoumessage.html");  
    }
    else 
    {
    // Failure message if the mail() function failed to trigger
    $error = "Something wrong !";
    }
}
?>

    <form class="mt-5 ml-5 mr-5" method="POST" action="" id="reused_form">
    <p id="contactForm" class="h4 text-center mt-5"><strong>Kontakta oss</strong></p>

    <!-- input text(Name) -->
    <div class="md-form">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix">*</i>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required >
        <label>Ditt namn</label>
    </div>
    <!-- Error name -->
    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
    <?php echo $error_name;?>
    </div>

    <!-- input email -->
    <div class="md-form mt-5">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix">*</i>
        <input type="email" id="name" name="email" id="email" class="form-control validate" required>
        <label data-error="Fel" data-success="Rätt">Din email</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Error email -->
    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
    <?php echo $error_email;?>
    </div>

    <div class="md-form mt-5">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required>
        <label>Ämne</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Error subject -->
    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
    <?php echo $error_subject;?>
    </div>


    <!-- input message -->
    <div class="md-form mt-5">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil prefix">*</i>
        <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" maxlength="5000" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3" required></textarea>
        <label>Meddelande</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Error message -->
    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
    <?php echo $error_message;?>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
    <?php echo $error;?>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
        <button class="btn danger-color" name="submit" type="submit">Skicka</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah the redirecting to the thank page is working but when I add the `php` tags in the html code it is something wrong with it :( I'm using visual studio code, and the text is just all white...

Comment: What's exactly the error message you're getting ? if it's about the editor,  you can just use any universal editor like Notepad++ and try again. Also, is the file  extension you're working on a *.HTML or *.PHP ?

Comment: I have as mentioned my `handler.php` and where I have the html the extension is `.html`

Comment: Did you try running the script exactly as i answered ? paste the whole thing in a file in index.php or filename.php or whatever.php and try

Comment: oh, so it needs to be a php file and not a html?

Comment: Oh, okey well that describes it :)

Comment: In fact, you can run php code in html files, but this needs some extras. Are you familiar with .htaccess ? you just need to add : AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html so it will be recognized as a valid php code

Comment: Would it help just changing the `.html` to `.php` ?

Comment: Judging from the editor you're using i can't guarantee it will work, use Notepad++ and paste the code and save it as .php just to be safe

Comment: Yes it did, the `php` code is valid now, but even if I let the for example name input empty it is just sending the email anyway... :(

Comment: You just need to check that there are no error messages, try replacing: if(mail($myemail, $subject, $mail)) with   if(mail($myemail, $subject, $mail) && ($error = "") && ($error_email = "") && ($error_name = "") && ($error_subject = "") && ($error_message = ""))

Comment: I saw now that you removed the action on the form but if I do that the page just reloads on submit :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need JavaScript, since the user will never leave the page.  If you make handler.php return some json instead of a page, this will be super easy.  First of all, I would put all your HTML in a file called `contact.html` so you can reference a different page from the one you're currently on.  If you add an empty `<p class="errorMsg"></p>` to the body wherever you want, it will be invisible until there's an error.

Then you can add the below scripts in a file called `submitForm.js`, adding `<script src="submitForm.js"></script>` to the head of `contact.html`.

```
const formElement = document.querySelector('form')
const formData = new FormData(formElement)
formElement.onsubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetch('/handler.php', { method: 'POST', body: formData })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      const errorElement = document.querySelector('errorMsg')
      errorElement.textContent = json.errorMsg
      if (json.errorMsg !== '') document.location = '/thankyoumessage.html'
    })
}
```

To break it down, fetch is a really easy way to make an ajax request.  Your user will stay on the current page, but your code will go out to the URL and get its data for use on the current page.  `fetch()` makes the request, and `then()` handles it synchronously after it gets the response.  Here, I'm chaining two `then()`s because I need to parse it into json before I can access that data.  The last `then()` is how you would handle the form submission.

[Learn more about fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Fetch is a new web API that relies on ES6 features and may not be compatible with older browsers.  I still encourage you to use it, because even if IE11 support is necessary, all it takes is a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) and a [syntax converter](https://babeljs.io/repl) to do all the work for you.

Now, to make fetch work like this, you'll need to put something in `handler.php`.  You can use all the code in your first snippet, leaving out the HTML.  You can return JSON just by building a string and echoing it, no html necessary.  You could accomplish that by changing your show_error() function calls to assigning an $errorMsg variable, like this.

```
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    $errorMsg = "Email adressen är inte giltig...";
}
```

then at the end of the file, instead of HTML you can write the JSON string like so.

```
echo '{ "errorMsg" : "' . $errorMsg . '" }';
```

Now, if your form still hit that page with an Email error for example, you would see this:

{ "errorMsg" : "Email adressen är inte giltig..." }

... Obviously you don't want to see that, but your JavaScript can see that without your user looking at it, and the JavaScript knows exactly what to do with that data, like we saw above.  Then you can add as many things as you want to that JSON, so your live JavaScript can do other things with it.

[Learn more about JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: Total overkill for something like a simple contact form.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean :(

Comment: @luddep I expanded my answer a little more.

Comment: @Adam how is this overkill?  This is by far the easiest and shortest way to make an ajax request.  If the handler is written in php, there's no way for it to handle a live client-side change.

Comment: Some simple JS can get this done without the need to learn a compiler, ES6 syntax/methods (worrying about older browsers).

Comment: A compiler does all the work for you though.  To each his own, I guess, but in my opinion the power and simplicity of ES6 far outweighs the small effort of initial setup.  That said, modern browsers all support it now, and this is also future-proofing your code.

Comment: @Adam If the op doesn't need IE11 support (they shouldn't), they don't need a compiler and I would argue that `fetch()` is both simpler to understand and simpler to maintain than a solution using `XMLHttpRequest` - especially for someone new to JS. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @luddep I apologize for being unclear, when I came back to read my answer it seemed incomplete.  I've added the full stack process to help walk you through it.  Feel free to ask questions!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will test it and come back with an answer or a question as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need this in a single page, but your form is directing to a second page (handler.php). You might benefit from having all of the functionality in a single script that loads both the form and handles form submission. The algorithm might go something like this:

```
$showForm = $showThankYou = false;
$errorMessage = '';
//if form submitted
  //check for errors 
  //if no errors
    $showThankYou = true;
  //else set error vars appropriately
    $errorMessage = '...';
    $showForm = true;
// else
$showForm = true;
```

From this point, you can include both your form and your thank you wrapped in conditionals. You can include your error message in your form html, as it will be blank when the form is first loaded.

```
if($showForm) {
  // form code block
}

if($showThankYou) {
  // thank you page
}
```

Comment: this is not recommended - much better to break scripts up

Answer (score 0):

It is going to /handler.php because is set on the form action:

```
<form class="mt-5 ml-5 mr-5" method="POST" action="handler.php" id="reused_form">
```

If you want to stay on the same page after form submits, you have to leave action empty. Instead, you have to set a conditional that checks if submit is set:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']){
       include('handler.php');
    }
```

Adding that code below your form will execute the script when the user hits submit (you have to modify it, it has to be an  not a button).

That's one way to do it using exclusively PHP. You also can put all the code of sending mail inside a function, and execute it when submit is send:

```
function sendMail(){
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message'])) 
    {

        /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
        $name = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['name']));
        $subject  = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['subject']));
        $email    = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['email']));
        $message = check_input(utf8_decode($_POST['message']));

        /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
        {
            show_error("Email adressen är inte giltig...");
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
        /*If name is empty show error message */
        if (empty($_POST['name'])) 
        {
            show_error("Du måste skriva in ditt namn...");
        }
        /*If email is empty show error message */
        if (empty($_POST['email'])) 
        {
            show_error("Du måste skriva in din email...");
        }
        /*If message is empty show error message */
        if (empty($_POST['message'])) 
        {
            show_error("Ett meddelande krävs om du önskar att få hjälp av oss...");
        }

        /* Prepare the message for the e-mail */
        $mail =utf8_decode("
        Hej!

        Ditt kontakt formulär har blivit besvarat av:

        Namn: $name

        E-mail: $email

        Kundens meddelande:
        $message

        Meddelande slut.
        ");

        echo "Tack för du kontaktar oss! \n Vi återkommer med ett svar så snart som möjligt!";

        /* Send the message using mail() function */
        mail($myemail, $subject, $mail);
    }
    else
    {
        ?><span><?php echo "Fyll i alla fälten...";?></span> <?php
    }
}
```

Changing the submit code

```
<?php 

include('handler.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    sendMail();
}
?>
```

There are any other ways, but this two maybe solve your problem in a way that only uses PHP.

Hope it helps.

PD: You have the same ID for the name and email input.